# Dynamically created button causes a postback even inside updatepanel

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

My buttons keep triggering postback even it is inside a update panel. I was able to make it work before on the same project with same approach and workded I'm no sure why it doesn't work in this project.

Client Side Code

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"/>
<div class="shop-cart-body">
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Panel runat="server" CssClass="shop-cart-item-container" ID="shopItemContainer">

                </asp:Panel>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
```

CodeBehind this is where the buttons and other stuff come from

```
public void LoadProducts()
    {
        ShopProduct sProduct = new ShopProduct();
        List<Product> products = sProduct.LoadProductJson();

        foreach (var product in products)
        {
            Panel productPanel = new Panel { CssClass = "shop-plan-product" };
            Panel pricePanel = new Panel { CssClass = "product-price" };
            Panel discountPanel = new Panel { CssClass = "product-discount" };
            Label titleLbl = new Label { Text = product.Title, CssClass = "product-title" };
            Label priceLbl = new Label { Text = string.Format("{0:n0}", ((product.Quantity * product.Price) - ((product.Quantity * product.Price) * product.Discount))) };
            Label pricedecLbl = new Label { Text = ".00/YR" };
            Label discountperLbl = new Label { Text = (product.Discount * 100).ToString() };
            Label discountLbl = new Label { Text = "% Discount" };
            Image pesoImg = new Image { ImageUrl = "~/Content/Images/peso.png" };
            Button cartBtn = new Button { Text = "Add to Cart", ID = "cbtn" + product.ProductID };
            cartBtn.Click += cartBtn_Click;
            BulletedList featuresBl = new BulletedList();


            ListItem featuresli1 = new ListItem { Text = "Unlimited teleconsultation" };
            int months = product.ValidationPeriod / 30;
            int years = months / 12;
            ListItem featuresli2 = new ListItem();
            if (years < 1)
            {
                if (months > 1)
                {
                    featuresli2.Text = months + " months access";
                }
                else if (months == 1)
                {
                    featuresli2.Text = months + " month access";
                }
                else
                {
                    featuresli2.Text = product.ValidationPeriod + " days access";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (months % 12 == 0)
                {
                    if (years == 1)
                    {
                        featuresli2.Text = years + " year access";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        featuresli2.Text = years + " years access";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    months = months % 12;

                    if (years == 1)
                    {
                        if (months == 1)
                        {
                            featuresli2.Text = years + " year " + months + " month access";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            featuresli2.Text = years + " year " + months + " months access";
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (months == 1)
                        {
                            featuresli2.Text = years + " years " + months + " month access";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            featuresli2.Text = years + " years " + months + " months access";
                        }
                    }

                }
            }


            ListItem featuresli3 = new ListItem { Text = "Good for " + product.Quantity + " person" };
            ListItem featuresli4 = new ListItem { Text = "24/7 teleconsultation" };
            ListItem featuresli5 = new ListItem { Text = "Medicine delivery" };
            ListItem featuresli6 = new ListItem { Text = "Medical certificate" };

            pricePanel.Controls.Add(pesoImg);
            pricePanel.Controls.Add(priceLbl);
            pricePanel.Controls.Add(pricedecLbl);

            discountPanel.Controls.Add(discountperLbl);
            discountPanel.Controls.Add(discountLbl);

            featuresBl.Items.Add(featuresli1);
            featuresBl.Items.Add(featuresli2);
            featuresBl.Items.Add(featuresli3);
            featuresBl.Items.Add(featuresli4);
            featuresBl.Items.Add(featuresli5);
            featuresBl.Items.Add(featuresli6);

            productPanel.Controls.Add(titleLbl);
            productPanel.Controls.Add(pricePanel);
            productPanel.Controls.Add(discountPanel);
            productPanel.Controls.Add(cartBtn);
            productPanel.Controls.Add(featuresBl);

            shopPlanProductContainer.Controls.Add(productPanel);

        }

    }
```

This where the click function is

```
protected void cartBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = Int32.Parse(((Button)sender).ID.Substring(4));

        List<CartItem> cartItems = new List<CartItem>();

        cartItems = (List<CartItem>)HttpContext.Current.Session["MedCart"];

        CartItem cartItem = new CartItem();
        cartItem.ProductID = id;
        cartItem.Quantity = 1;

        cartItems.Add(cartItem);

    }
```

Hope someone can help sorry for the long code i put it all to be understood completely.

Comment: After this, 
    public void LoadProducts()
    {
        //Check the Postback
         If(!IsPostback)
         {
                // Do the Stuff
         }
     }

Comment: what do you mean sir? vivek ramasamy

Comment: Sir but im preventing a normal postback that it wont refresh

Comment: Sadly sir @vivekramasamy it did't work still postback normally

Comment: Where you are calling this LoadProducts() method

Comment: in the cartBtn_Click , you can put the (!IsPostBack)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use update mode as conditional and another attribute ChildrenAsTriggers. Try the below.

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"/>
<div class="shop-cart-body">
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Panel runat="server" CssClass="shop-cart-item-container" ID="shopItemContainer">

                </asp:Panel>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
```

Comment: Sir it stills does a full postback what do you think could be the way to debug this and find a way to solve Thank you @Chidambaram

Comment: Then once the page is loaded, press F12 and check the DOM objects inside the update panel for any autopostback, also check any scripts connected to DOM objects which could cause a postback.

Comment: Does it matter if the form is inside the page itself rather than the site master? Because one of my projects with the same update panel approach worked and its form is in the site master